# Changing installation directory of GitLab

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-omnibus, gitlab-api, gitlab-ce

I am trying to install Gitlab (Community Edition) on Linux CentOS. According to my knowledge, the configuration files are stored in etc/config and the data are stored in /var/opt/Gitlab. But I want to change it to a custom directory. Is it possible to achieve that? If possible, how can I do that? Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The use of /opt/gitlab and /etc/gitlab is hard-coded i guess. For /var/opt/gitlab, consider mounting a filesystem at /var/opt/gitlab (preferred) ?

Reference - https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/issues/198